# Datagrab stuck at 95%

Tags: datagrab, import

I'm using Datagrab to import a feed from Blogger. 
However it seems to be getting stuck at `Running - 24 out of 25 records (96%)`.

This is locally - any ideas on how best to debug why this is not completing?

Cole

Comment: check the feed first and make sure that it validates

Comment: Same problem here. I triggered it remote for the first time, and it seemingly worked since it said "Import complete", but when I got back to the plugin and refresh, it's stuck at "RUNNING 41/42 records (98%)"